# newpxtext math font displays binomial coefficients with too much space in small font

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, fontsize

When I use a small font (\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}) I get the following badly spaced binomial coefficients.

[image: bad binomials]

Notice how the brackets are squashed and the entries look shifted up and down. It looks like this in \fontsize{10pt}{11pt}, which is nicer

[image: good binomials]

I want this font and I want the font size. I'm making a Maths revision guide (cheatsheet) and it has to be dense information on an A4 landscape sheet. This is non-negotiable.

What can I do?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, landscape, margin=6pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[tighter]{newpxtext}

\begin{document}

{\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\selectfont
  $$(a + bx)^n = a^n + \binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b + \binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}b^2 + \dots
    + \binom{n}{r}a^{n-r}b^r + \dots + b^n$$\par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why not `\scriptsize` (which is the same thing?) Perhaps you would prefer to typeset an over-size 10pt document scaled down by 70%. at small sizes `(` are discrete glyphs from the font so do not scale smoothly. Also `$$` should not be used in latex, although it makes no difference here

Comment: If you use `newpxtex`, for the accompanying math you should load `newpxmath`. Try and see the difference.

Comment: @egreg unfortunately I don't like the newpxmath math font as much as the one from the newpxtext.

Answer (score 1):

Especially if you are short of space you may prefer a 10pt setting scaled 70% either the whole document or just the math. Here I scale just the math to show side by side.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, landscape, margin=6pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,graphicx}
\usepackage[tighter]{newpxtext}

\begin{document}

{\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\selectfont
  $$(a + bx)^n = a^n + \binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b + \binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}b^2 + \dots
    + \binom{n}{r}a^{n-r}b^r + \dots + b^n$$\par}

{\scriptsize
  $$(a + bx)^n = a^n + \binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b + \binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}b^2 + \dots
    + \binom{n}{r}a^{n-r}b^r + \dots + b^n$$\par}

  \begin{center}
\scalebox{0.7}{$\displaystyle(a + bx)^n = a^n + \binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b + \binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}b^2 + \dots
    + \binom{n}{r}a^{n-r}b^r + \dots + b^n$}
 \end{center}


\end{document}
```

Despite the title, newpx fonts are not involved at all here, you are using computer modern math. Here is the same using px math fonts.

```
\usepackage[tighter]{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
```

[image]

Comment: (a+b)^n  A mistake in the question and in the answer.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro x=1 ? :-)

Comment: You are right - never touch a math teacher (i was)!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So would I put the entire document in a scalebox? Seems a bit drastic no? Although I have it as A4 for printing, so maybe something like this is the solution. Something that prints ok on A4 but by scaling...

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro You're right actually. Good catch.

Comment: @LostInHilbertSpace no no need to put the whole doc in a scalebox, just use `geometry` to set an over-sized page that scales by 70% if printed to A4

Comment: How does one do this @DavidCarlisle?

Comment: `\geometry{a3paper, landscape, margin=6pt}` for example then select scale-to fit when printing

Comment: Ok thanks. Just on what you said about how I'm using computer modern math... if I remove newpxtext, I get a different maths font. If I add lmodern, it's a different maths font. So newpxtext seems to be adding a different font and I thought computer modern was the default.

Comment: @LostInHilbertSpace the default math is computer modern and `newpxtext` does not change that. If you use `lmodern` package text and math change to Latin Modern, which is similar to Computer Modern (derived from it) but different